# Picture attachment download keeps using same file name

Tags: downloading, images, files, file-transfer, file-management

with my Samusung Galaxy S II Epic 4G (Sprint) every time i go to save an attached picture from a text message the menu pops up with the same file name (everytime!) and a checkbox. i have to remember to go into my downloads picture folder and change the previous picture's file name, which is stupid and tedious. is there anyway to reset this for downloaded pics? or set it to auto assign a different file name each time??

Comment: You might have luck with a different text messaging app from the Market.

Answer (score 1):

Always been that way and if you don't change the name it will overwrite the image.

Till now, haven't found any fix or a work around, besides using another APP from the market.

This two have been recommend in the past and work just fine:

[GO SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms&hl=en)

[Handcent SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms)

---

Just confirmed and this [Google Play Search](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=SMS&c=apps), still gives you the two above app as the best rated ones.

Comment: Go SMS was put in the spot, not-so-long ago, there was privacy issues about it when someone raised the issue and yielded, what appeared to be, some iffy code that was transmitting information to china... Do not know if that has been resolved ever since, but do recall a discussion on modaco about this

Comment: am still hunting for the thread there on modaco...

Comment: Found a related issue at [GO SMS Pro website](http://gosms.goforandroid.com/?p=130#comment-801), but was posted under the **GO SMS Pro V3.73** on October 25th, 2011... Being from an Anonymous source and having no responses till this day, it's likely to be an isolated case! **Ps:** Current version for
GO SMS Pro is V4.52.

Comment: Ahh cheers mate for that :)